# android-java-Encrypt & decrypt string between php and java

Tags: java, php, android

I'm wring an android application . 
I want to encode some of my data with php and send it to my app and decrypt it in the app and read the actual data .

How can I do so ?

thanks you

Comment: Well, What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to use base64 , I tried 3 diffrent codes like this one but it has an error . String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("travelbuddy" + ":" + "travelbuddy").getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);  . "DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field"